# Trigger function for next element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

some advice needed for following case:

```
<ul class="acc">
  <li class="collapse-trigger"></li> 
  <ul class="collapse-ul" style="height: 0;">
    <li>some content</li>
    <li>some content</li>
  </ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="collapse-trigger"></li> 
  <ul class="collapse-ul" style="height: 0;">
    <li>some content</li>
    <li>some content</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I have a main `ul` which has a few `li`s. Some of these have a class `collapse-trigger` which fires an animation for the **NEXT** item `.collapse-ul`. It is important that depending on which `collapse-trigger` is clicked it only the next item with `.collapse-ul` of it gets fired.

```
$('.collapse-trigger').click(function() { 
  $(this).next().animate({height: 500}, 'slow'); // how to get the next collapse-ul
});
```

Comment: That HTML does not look valid. `ul` can be a child of `li` but not a direct child of `ul`. Start by fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructure your HTML to be valid (see also here [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y375Lz98/)), e.g.:

```
<ul class="acc">
    <li class="collapse-trigger"></li>
    <li class="collapse-ul" style="height: 0;">
        <ul>
            <li>some content</li>
            <li>some content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="collapse-trigger"></li>
    <li class="collapse-ul" style="height: 0;">
        <ul>
            <li>some content</li>
            <li>some content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now you can provide a selector to [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next):

```
$(this).next('.collapse-ul').animate({height: 500}, 'slow');
```

Comment: *"After fixing your html"* - OP's HTML can be fixed in many ways - by moving the `<ul>` into `li.collapse-trigger`, by moving the `<ul>` into an `<li>` after `.collapse-trigger`, the answer will not work for such cases... Please also show the *correct* HTML structure that'll work with your answer.

Comment: @TJ Thanks for your suggestion.I really appreciate your feedback. I've set up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y375Lz98/) and added the HTML structure to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: @John ideally `collapse-ul` the class of `<ul>` to be collapsed. It is better to add a button or hyperlink with `collapse-trigger` class inside the `<li>` followed by the `<ul>`, so that it'll work accoding to your code and you don't need an additional `<li>`...

Answer (score 1):

Your markup isn't valid. You need to nest your `<ul class="collapse-ul">` inside a `<li>`tag.
I've created a working JS Fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j35Lwwf3/).